# Conflict in arduinoJson.h and WiFiClientSecure.h in ESP8266?

Tags: json, parsing, arduino, esp8266

So I'm using this code:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

//Wifi data
const char* ssid = "Llibertat!";
const char* password = "xxx";

//Nest_api data
const char* host = "firebase-apiserver10-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com";
const int httpsPort = 9553; //443;
const char* BearerKey = "c.xxx";
// SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate
const char* fingerprint = "87:CB:F2:E6:44:C0:AA:F2:4C:28:B2:97:85:70:18:92:45:1B:A4:57";

//declaring GPIO's
int gpio13Led = 13;
int gpio12Relay = 12;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(gpio13Led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(gpio13Led, HIGH);
  pinMode(gpio12Relay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(gpio12Relay, HIGH);




  //connecting to wifi

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }//ok
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  //SERVER UITLEZEN


  /*
    //connecting to client
    WiFiClientSecure client;
    Serial.print("connecting to ");
    Serial.println(host);

      if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
      Serial.println("connection failed");
      return;
    }//ok

    String url = "/";
    Serial.print("requesting URL: ");
    Serial.println(url);


    //requesting data from server
    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                 "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                 "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
                 "Authorization: Bearer " + BearerKey + "\r\n\r\n"
                 );

    Serial.println("request sent");
    while (client.connected()) {
     String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
      //Serial.println(line);
      if (line == "\r") {
        Serial.println("headers received");
        break;
      }
    }
    //print return
    //while (client.available()) {
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');

      Serial.println("reply was:");
      Serial.println("==========");
      Serial.println(line);
      //Serial.println("==========");
      //Serial.println("closing connection");
      digitalWrite(gpio13Led, LOW);


    }
    Reading JSON
    Serial.println("line:");
    Serial.println(line);
     json = line.c_str();

    String json = "";

  */


  parseJson();

}

void parseJson () {

  const char* json = "{\"devices\":{\"thermostats\":{\"e97ayjdpIOkPa4vZFxHggZMXiHKfhsyU\":{\"humidity\":40,\"locale\":\"nl-NL\",\"temperature_scale\":\"C\",\"is_using_emergency_heat\":false,\"has_fan\":false,\"software_version\":\"5.6.6-4\",\"has_leaf\":false,\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7XyH-9WDdVgA\",\"device_id\":\"e97ayjdpIOkPa4vZFxHggZMXiHKfhsyU\",\"name\":\"Downstairs\",\"can_heat\":true,\"can_cool\":false,\"target_temperature_c\":21,\"target_temperature_f\":70,\"target_temperature_high_c\":24,\"target_temperature_high_f\":75,\"target_temperature_low_c\":20,\"target_temperature_low_f\":68,\"ambient_temperature_c\":16,\"ambient_temperature_f\":62,\"away_temperature_high_c\":24,\"away_temperature_high_f\":76,\"away_temperature_low_c\":8.5,\"away_temperature_low_f\":48,\"eco_temperature_high_c\":24,\"eco_temperature_high_f\":76,\"eco_temperature_low_c\":8.5,\"eco_temperature_low_f\":48,\"is_locked\":false,\"locked_temp_min_c\":20,\"locked_temp_min_f\":68,\"locked_temp_max_c\":22,\"locked_temp_max_f\":72,\"sunlight_correction_active\":false,\"sunlight_correction_enabled\":true,\"structure_id\":\"vEJb634MNif-xVxcn3hIdIAAdT2p5L7beo2amUiTuBVoEPy3C0PAFw\",\"fan_timer_active\":false,\"fan_timer_timeout\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"fan_timer_duration\":15,\"previous_hvac_mode\":\"\",\"hvac_mode\":\"heat\",\"time_to_target\":\">120\",\"time_to_target_training\":\"ready\",\"where_name\":\"Downstairs\",\"label\":\"\",\"name_long\":\"Downstairs Thermostat\",\"is_online\":true,\"last_connection\":\"2018-02-20T14:49:32.629Z\",\"hvac_state\":\"heating\"}}},\"structures\":{\"NzsPBklZNQBC4FVqmRUaVLqMhPVJII3IzQ0QfhReeGv_UCagNdtMhg\":{\"name\":\"Structure 1\",\"country_code\":\"US\",\"time_zone\":\"America/Los_Angeles\",\"away\":\"home\",\"structure_id\":\"NzsPBklZNQBC4FVqmRUaVLqMhPVJII3IzQ0QfhReeGv_UCagNdtMhg\",\"wheres\":{\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6FUQ2RVTLC5w\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6FUQ2RVTLC5w\",\"name\":\"Backyard\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG4POqHyZw5GHQ\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG4POqHyZw5GHQ\",\"name\":\"Basement\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5QjU1FA_slkA\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5QjU1FA_slkA\",\"name\":\"Bedroom\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5kuu8P9K1TFQ\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5kuu8P9K1TFQ\",\"name\":\"Den\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG4ncylMQyZn-g\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG4ncylMQyZn-g\",\"name\":\"Dining Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7XyH-9WDdVgA\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7XyH-9WDdVgA\",\"name\":\"Downstairs\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5rtDphaQytaQ\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5rtDphaQytaQ\",\"name\":\"Driveway\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5Z5XxmZr9Aeg\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5Z5XxmZr9Aeg\",\"name\":\"Entryway\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7r62EA7u7DWw\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7r62EA7u7DWw\",\"name\":\"Family Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6o_Kr6tv-CSA\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6o_Kr6tv-CSA\",\"name\":\"Front Yard\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5OO0kfgPRADw\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5OO0kfgPRADw\",\"name\":\"Guest House\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5AMihmAgobTw\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5AMihmAgobTw\",\"name\":\"Guest Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6MLDlLEu4-2A\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6MLDlLEu4-2A\",\"name\":\"Hallway\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5t08bO8j0Mzg\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5t08bO8j0Mzg\",\"name\":\"Kids Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7p1ASlDNUnHg\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7p1ASlDNUnHg\",\"name\":\"Kitchen\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7uLdRQIIIvww\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7uLdRQIIIvww\",\"name\":\"Living Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5W7d3KtKxzfg\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5W7d3KtKxzfg\",\"name\":\"Master Bedroom\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6arlkBKu_K8Q\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6arlkBKu_K8Q\",\"name\":\"Office\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7gc73riRgkvw\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7gc73riRgkvw\",\"name\":\"Outside\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6c07Ca7PZt2A\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6c07Ca7PZt2A\",\"name\":\"Upstairs\"}}},\"vEJb634MNif-xVxcn3hIdIAAdT2p5L7beo2amUiTuBVoEPy3C0PAFw\":{\"name\":\"CNT/FAI\",\"country_code\":\"BE\",\"time_zone\":\"Europe/Brussels\",\"away\":\"home\",\"thermostats\":[\"e97ayjdpIOkPa4vZFxHggZMXiHKfhsyU\"],\"structure_id\":\"vEJb634MNif-xVxcn3hIdIAAdT2p5L7beo2amUiTuBVoEPy3C0PAFw\",\"wheres\":{\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6FUQ2RVTLC5w\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6FUQ2RVTLC5w\",\"name\":\"Backyard\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG4POqHyZw5GHQ\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG4POqHyZw5GHQ\",\"name\":\"Basement\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5QjU1FA_slkA\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5QjU1FA_slkA\",\"name\":\"Bedroom\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5kuu8P9K1TFQ\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5kuu8P9K1TFQ\",\"name\":\"Den\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG4ncylMQyZn-g\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG4ncylMQyZn-g\",\"name\":\"Dining Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7XyH-9WDdVgA\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7XyH-9WDdVgA\",\"name\":\"Downstairs\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5rtDphaQytaQ\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5rtDphaQytaQ\",\"name\":\"Driveway\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5Z5XxmZr9Aeg\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5Z5XxmZr9Aeg\",\"name\":\"Entryway\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7r62EA7u7DWw\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7r62EA7u7DWw\",\"name\":\"Family Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6o_Kr6tv-CSA\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6o_Kr6tv-CSA\",\"name\":\"Front Yard\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5OO0kfgPRADw\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5OO0kfgPRADw\",\"name\":\"Guest House\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5AMihmAgobTw\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5AMihmAgobTw\",\"name\":\"Guest Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6MLDlLEu4-2A\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6MLDlLEu4-2A\",\"name\":\"Hallway\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5t08bO8j0Mzg\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5t08bO8j0Mzg\",\"name\":\"Kids Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7p1ASlDNUnHg\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7p1ASlDNUnHg\",\"name\":\"Kitchen\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7uLdRQIIIvww\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7uLdRQIIIvww\",\"name\":\"Living Room\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5W7d3KtKxzfg\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG5W7d3KtKxzfg\",\"name\":\"Master Bedroom\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6arlkBKu_K8Q\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6arlkBKu_K8Q\",\"name\":\"Office\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7gc73riRgkvw\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG7gc73riRgkvw\",\"name\":\"Outside\"},\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6c07Ca7PZt2A\":{\"where_id\":\"YygkopgUUc_cIFnCNG7GRDIIQnENO0ScVx9Pa78qfG6c07Ca7PZt2A\",\"name\":\"Upstairs\"}}}},\"metadata\":{\"access_token\":\"c.xxx\",\"client_version\":2,\"user_id\":\"z.1.1.EdSQPfAYvEeh8u6g2NyARyancELYiLqqn77VnzioUvo=\"}}";
  Serial.println(json);
  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(10838);
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);
  //Serial.print("JsonObject: ");
  //Serial.println((int)root["devices"]["thermostats"]["e97ayjdpIOkPa4vZFxHggZMXiHKfhsyU"]);
  JsonObject& thermostat = root["devices"]["thermostats"]["e97ayjdpIOkPa4vZFxHggZMXiHKfhsyU"];
  const char* hvacState = thermostat["hvac_state"]; // "heating"
  Serial.println("hvac:");
  Serial.print(hvacState);
}

void loop() {
}
```

To check if everything works I've placed a big deal of code in comment. By this I could test the code piece by piece. Now I notice that in the current configuration the class `parseJson()` is executed like you can see in the serial monitor result:

```
onnecting to Llibertat!
.........
WiFi connected
IP address: 
192.168.178.31
{"devicesxxx
hvac:
heating
```

But from the moment I take the code out of comment the `parseJson()` doesn't work anymore. I mean, I don't get any result from `hvacState` In fact, If I just bring this code out of comment:

```
WiFiClientSecure client;
    Serial.print("connecting to ");
    Serial.println(host);

      if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
      Serial.println("connection failed");
      return;
    }//ok
```

The parsing also stops working. Can it be that the `WifiClientSecure` and the `ArduinoJson` are conflicting with each other? 
Did somebody else had a similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running out of memory. Try separating your HTTPS call and your JSON processing into two separate function calls. You can stream the JSON data to a file, exit the function, and then read the file later straight into ArduinoJson. Just make sure you've used the ArduinoJson calculator to allocate a big enough JsonBuffer. If it still bombs out reading Json, you can chunk the Json data by searching for a delimiter and reading a bit at a time into the Json buffer.

In your example, put the commented out code in its own function call. Call it from setup, then call parseJson from setup.